# Google Sheets Import Range Issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have three different formulas that keep #REFing out and need help with:

=ARRAYFORMULA({Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!A3:H10000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!A10001:H20000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!A20001:H31486")})
=ARRAYFORMULA({Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!I3:P10000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!I10001:P20000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!I20001:P31486")})
=ARRAYFORMULA({Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!Q3:X10000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!Q10001:X20000");Importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!Q20001:X31486")})

Why is this import range not working? Is there something I can edit to help these formulas flow through better? Thanks for all of the help!

I have added in the last half into the formulas to break up the formulas a bit and that seemed to help temporarily.

Comment: Hello! Tried them and found them without error. I don't know if you have a specific reason for dividing them in three importrange in an array. =importrange($A$1,$H$1&"!A3:H31846") just would return the same, if not mistaken

Comment: Thanks for the help! If the formula works, could it be I have an issue with the source data?

Comment: Is your source data that long?? 31846 rows??, Some spelling error on sheet name in H1?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output